# How to make a lookup in different databases using nestjs and mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I would like to ask if it's possible to make a lookup to a different databases using nestjs and mongodb.
I know how to make connections to different databases and naming them, but this is not the case, because the connections are working separately. I want to make a lookup which is looking for the different connections at the same time. It's possible in express for sure so I suppose it has to be possible in nestjs too. Thanks for any help!